# how to remove the add friend and start hangout page from my Hangout API?

Tags: google-hangouts

i am using the hangout api in my site as there are certain groups need to get involved in the hangout, 
As the first person of the group when comes to the site is creating a hangout URL from the HANGOUT API, and the rest of the group members will the get the link directly of the hangout they don't need to create the hangout.
The idea is working just have two problems:

1. When the first person in the group is creating the hangout URL he get the page START THE HANGOUT page and after closing it the user is get to my API.
2. User will not be able to add members in the hangout the persons having links can only join the hangout

Answer (score 0):

See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-developers/r_f7iweZ7c8) on something similar. It links to a Youtube video which may be in the right direction.

I think Google has not made what you're asking for very easy (yet).